# The evaluation of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \! e^{-2 |x - u| -3 |u|} \, \mathrm{d}u$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I am trying to solve this integral, however my attempts haven't worked out yet.

My general approach to solving equations involving modulus functions is to split them into cases, although I don't know if this will work here.

This is my attempt:

Let $x$ and $u$ both be positive.

Then we could have something like the following:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \! e^{-2x - 5u} \, \mathrm{d}u$

$e^{-2x} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \! e^{- 5u} \, \mathrm{d}u$

$e^{-2x} \biggl[-\frac{1}{5} e^{-5u} \biggr]_{-\infty}^{\infty}$

But this seems to diverge. Can anyone help me solve this integral? I apologise if I've made a silly error somewhere.

Comment: $u$ is a variable. You can't assume $x>u$. Although you're right about the divergency part. If you do the casework, the part that $x>u$ is divergent.

Comment: Noted thank you, but I am confused about the cases

Comment: The cases are $-\infty<u<min\{0,x\}$ and $min\{0,x\}<u<max\{0,x\}$ and $max\{0,x\}<u<+\infty$ and the integral in the first case is divergent.

Comment: Constraint-1  $u\geq x$, Constraint-2 $u<x$, Constraint-3 $u\geq 0$, Constraint-4 $u<0$.  Either Constraint-1 or Constraint-2 holds, but not both.  Ditto Constraint-3 and Constraint-4.  You then have 4 cases: where Case 1 is (for example) Constraint-1 + Constraint-3.  Note that depending on the value of $x$, one of the 4 cases may be impossible.  Unclear to me whether you need to consider **fixed** $x<0$ and $x\geq 0$ separately.  By **fixed** I intend that within the integration, $x$ is *some unknown fixed value*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Case I.** $x \ge 0$

Then,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2|x-u|-3|u|} du
 = \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-2(x-u)-3u} du
 + \int_0^x e^{-2(x-u)+3u} du
 + \int_x^\infty e^{2(x-u)+3u} du
$$
Can you integrate?

**Case II.** $x<0$

Can you write a similar decomposition over $(-\infty,x)\cup(x,0)\cup(0,\infty)$?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is your first integral not divergent however? The $\int_{-\infty}^{0} \! e^{-2(x-u)-3u} \, \mathrm{d}u$ ?

Comment: @ES5775 indeed,
$$
e^{-2x} \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-u} du
$$
does indeed diverge which implies the whole integral diverges in this case. Then there is a second case...

Comment: Thank you, I got $\int_{-\infty}^{x} \! e^{-2(x-u) + 3u} \mathrm{d}u \, + \, \int_{x}^{0} \! e^{2(x-u) + 3u} \, \mathrm{d}x \, + \, \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{2(x-u)-3u} \mathrm{d}u$, is that correct?

Comment: @ES5775 indeed, this is correct\